# How REQUEST_URI works to protect an entire website but allow access to 1 specific file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cakephp-3.0

I use the code below to protect my whole website under cakephp3 except for one url "/specifi/url" and It works well.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "\/specific\/url$" NOPASSWD=true
AuthUserFile /home/f/www/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=NOPASSWD
```

The problem is that I want to be more strict with the REGEX. So I modify the first line that way:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^\/specific\/url$" NOPASSWD=true
```

and it doesn't work anymore. Any idea why ?

Comment: Spaces, or other non-printing characters?

Comment: @anubhava > Here is the URL: https://example.com/specific/url?key=12345 and there is no space or non-printing chars

Comment: Making that small change (adding the start-of-string anchor) to the regex won't have made any difference if that is the URL being requested. If you are suing cakephp3 then you presumably have other directives in your `.htaccess` file - please edit your question to include the complete file.

Comment: What's with the backslashes escaping those forward slashes, why are those in there to begin with?